# Handling Spaces In Substring Searches In Bash Shell Scripts

Tags: bash, shell, substring

I'm using the following to determine if either substring is present in a $mainString in a Bash (ver 3.2.25) shell script:

```
if [[ $mainString = *cat* || $mainSubstring = *blue cheese* ]]; then
    echo "FOUND"
else
    echo "NOT FOUND"
fi
```

But I keep getting the following error because of the space in "blue cheese". How do you handle spaces in the substring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape the space:

```
$mainSubString = *blue\ cheese*
```

or quote the non-wildcard portions, one example of which is

```
$mainSubString = *'blue cheese'*
```

Often, it is better to store the pattern in a variable, both to simplify the quoting and to make the `[[...]]` expression more concise. Note that you must not quote the parameter expansion, as glenn jackman points out in his comment.

```
pattern="*blue cheese*"
if [[ $mainString = *cat* || $mainSubstring = $pattern ]]; then
```

Comment: +1. If you put the pattern in a variable, you must not quote the variable: `[[ $mainSubstring = "$pattern" ]]` returns false.